# slideshow images height adjustment

Tags: css, jsp

I am trying to create an jsp home page with slide show. I am using eclipse ide, JSP,CSS and JS. I am able to get the slide show everything works just fine but the height of the images in the slideshow are different i have given height as 60% for all images. But each image shows thier own original height. Can anyone guide what needs to be corrected. Below is the code.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: none
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="kn">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
  </header>

  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="images/1.jpg" height="50%" width="100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="images/2.jpg" height="50%" width="100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="images/3.jpg" height="50%" width="100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="images/4.jpg" height="50%" width="100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="images/5.jpg" height="50%" width="100%">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

  </div>
  <br>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
  </div>
  <script src="js/home.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Define height value for .mySlides or .fade and I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SO,

you need to define height for your container of slideshow in your case it is **slideshow-container** so in css,

```
   .slideshow-container{
height:300px;
}
```

this should do the trick.!, hope this helps.